# Remove sticky navbar on mobile view sticky js

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky

I have used sticky js plugin to make navbar sticky on the top but on mobile, half of the space is taken by navbar so I don't want to make sticky on mobile. How to remove sticky function on mobile only???

```
        <script>
            $(window).load(function(){
                $(".navbar.navbar-inverse").sticky({ 
                    topSpacing: 0
                });
            });
        </script>
```

I have used above function to make sticky.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 if(window.innerWidth < 360)
 {
    $(".navbar.navbar-inverse").unstick();
 }
 });
 </script>
```

Call this function after specific screen width for mobile view using javascript

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use vanilla js?
what you can end up doing is a custom sticky behaviour and then disabling it just on mobile with javascript. You don't want to be hacking around a jquery plugin when it's super simple to be doing that yourself.

Instead of making that switch for device specific (which you can by looking at the browser agent) I would recommend doing that by resolution (screen.width) That way you will be device agnostic and become only resolution aware :) it does simplify things

I wrote an article about sticky positioning that you might want to check as well [here](https://dioxmio.medium.com/sticky-done-the-right-way-880af0122a71) It is about on how to best achieve that.